# The entity "raquo" was referenced, but not declared

Tags: title, feedburner

Would anyone happen to know why I keep getting the error:

"The URL does not appear to reference a valid XML file. We encountered the following problem: Error on line 163: The entity "raquo" was referenced, but not declared."

When I put CmChatLive.com into feedburner?

http://feedburner.google.com/fb/a/addfeed

I am unable to edit the output of that title entity.

Comment: Does [this post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/feed-showing-error-on-line-31-at-column-34-entity-raquo-not-defined) help?

Comment: Thank you that works.  I do not know how to mark this as resolved, or give you the credit you deserve, please advise.

Comment: I have to refer you to that post in my comment in an Answer below... Give me about 3 minutes.  Since the answer exists you check it, then we delete the comments from this one for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [this forum post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/feed-showing-error-on-line-31-at-column-34-entity-raquo-not-defined) in the WordPress.org Support Forums will help.  If you'd like me to research it more, I'll update this post as I go... I hate telling someone to disable something without having a fix when it's re-enabled.